# protractor how to get text from div?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

Trying to get the text inside my div:

```
<div class="ng-scope ng-binding">
         Hello this is it!
</div>
```

In my jasmine script I have (using xpath):

```
var helloTxt=driver.findElement(by.xpath('//*[@id="top"]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div'));
expect(helloTxt.getText()).toBe('Hello this is it!');
```

the code looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
        <div data-ng-repeat="message in getMessages() track by $index">
            {{message}}
        </div>
</div>
```

How can I check get the messages in `{{message}}`?
Is there another way to access this div without using xpath? Or how can I fix this?

Comment: Look like some bindings are there waiting to be used, can you share the source code instead of the angular compiled html?

Comment: Also: avoid `findElement` and prefer `element(by.xxxx` every time you can. When possible use a better selector rather than `xpath` specially making your test so dependent to that nested div location.

Comment: @Leo I added some html:)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Target all messages available inside the `container`

```
var messageElms = $('.container').all(by.binding('message'));
```

Assuming you expect only 1 message:

```
expect(messageElms.count()).toBe(1);
```

Assuming you expect that *Hello* to be the first message:

```
expect(messageElms.get(0).getText()).toEqual('Hello this is it!');
```